# How do I remove item-view on fetch?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have a UserCollection which is handled by a UsersView (list). Single elements, models, are handled as UserView.

When I now fetch a new UserCollection (other url) than the collection object itselfs updates (containes the new user models) but the html list remains.

ListView:

```
    var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "ul",
        className: "contacts unstyled",
        events: {

        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new UserCollection();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.addContact, this);
            this.collection.bind('remove', this.removeContact, this); // not getting called
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.listContacts, this);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html();

            return this;
        },
        listContacts: function(contacts) {
            contacts.each(function(contact) {
                this.$el.append(new ContactView({ model: contact }).render().el);
            }.bind(this));
        },
        addContact: function(contact) {
            this.$el.append(new ContactView({ model: contact }).render().el);
        },
        // this is not getting executed
        removeContact: function(contact) {
            console.log(["removeContact fired"]);
            contact.unset();
        }
    });
```

Item-View

```
    var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        className: "contact",
        template: _.template(ContactTemplate),
        events: {
            "mouseenter li.contact": "expandOptions"
            , "mouseleave li.contact": "collapseOptions"
            , "click": "removeContact"
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('remove', this.remove, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
            this.model.bind('unset', this.remove, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

            return this;
        },
        expandOptions: function() {

        },
        collapseOptions: function() {

        },
        removeContact: function(e) {
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });
```

So which event is fired when a Backbone.Collection removes items internally (e.g. fetch) and how do I listen to it?

Comment: First of all, bind this (info: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this), preferably with the `_.bindAll`-function. Then before all each type functions, do `var self = this;`, and everywhere you want to call this (as in the this within the function you call each from) use `self`.

Comment: Then see if it isn't working properly

Comment: @jakee why is self recommand over .bind(this)?

Comment: they're the same thing, didn't notice you had that there, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a *Collection* is *fetched* and the [the model data returns from the server](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) the Collection calls `reset()` and fires the `reset` event.

So is in your `reset` binding where you have to *empty()* your DOM element. In your case in your `listContacts()`.

Comment: Hi, but even when I do a render before listContacts nothing changes. I also can't beleave that keeping all item-views alive is a good idea?

Comment: @kyogron [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) does not clean the DOM content but returning it. Use [jQuery.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Comment: Ok I did that. I additionally had to remove { add: true, remove: true } from the fetch options. However what is about the memory thing. What happens with views which are removed from the document but not unset?

Comment: @kyogron `{ add: true, remove: true }` shouldn't be necessary if what you want is replace completely the Collection content. About the memory leak removing Views there is [a lot of literature about it](https://www.google.es/search?q=ghost+views+backbone)